# normal high asterisk in equation mode

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

I was looking back at some of the equations that I had written and noticed that the asterisks weren't behaving how *I* was expecting it to (I also understand that my expectations may differ from other users).

The point is, I'm trying to get Q* but instead I get something like this Q✶. I've tried using the caret (^) for superscript but it looks awfully small.

Does anyone know a way to get the asterisk to behave as if it is in the normal text environment while in the equation mode?

Comment: The text asterisk is raised, while the math asterisk is used for denoting an operation; `\mbox{*}` or `\text{*}` if you load `amsmath` will do. But in general `$Q^{*}$` is preferred.

Comment: would that work if I needed it in equation mode?, i.e.

\begin{equation}
....
\end{equation}

Comment: \mbox does it. thanks! just copy your comment as an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The text asterisk is raised, while the math asterisk is used for denoting an operation.

You can use `\mbox{*}` or `\text{*}` (if you load `amsmath`).

However, in general `$Q^{*}$` is preferred.

You can get the behavior automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%% magic code starts
\mathcode`*=\string"8000
\begingroup
\catcode`*=\active
\xdef*{\noexpand\textup{\string*}}
\endgroup
%%% magic code ends

\begin{document}
$a^{\ast} Q*$
\end{document}
```

I've added `\ast` that is the usual math asterisk for a comparison.

[image]

I'd recommend using the first form.